# How can i check my word for a specific letter from a user input?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a hangman game how can I check my word for a specific letter from a user input? I know there isn't much code here but I'm stuck and cant quite find any answers to my problem

```
//word or phrase in variable
{
 string word = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
 //blanked out word / phrase
 string blanked = "___________________________________"
 // #of incorrect guesses 
 int guesses = 6
 // letter guesses
 string letter_guess = input("enter a letter guess: ")

  //start loop
 while()
 {

 }
 //if guess incorrect do this
 // how do i check the var for correct letters

 //elif guess correct do this

 //elif out of guesses do this

 //else do this
}
```

Comment: Iterate through `word`. Compare `word[i]` with user input. If they are the same replace `blanked[i]` with that letter. If there are no more underscores in `blanked` then all letters are found. `blanked` should be a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string`. It's easier that way.

Comment: There is quite a bit wrong in the little code that you provided. Missing `;`'s to start. Also what is `input()`? That is not defined anywhere, I think what you are going for is something like: `Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter guess: ");` `var letter_guess = Console.ReadLine();` to capture user input.

Comment: i did a sloppy conversion from python my bad

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, I'm sure. This may not be the best approach, but below you will find one example.

Basically the approach is to convert your word into a character array. Then, loop through each character in the array and compare with `letterGuess`. As you will notice, `TryParse` is used here, this will take care of any unwanted input from the user.

If there is a match, `blanked[i] = word[i];` will essentially replace the appropriate `'_'` blank character in `blanked` with the correct letter guess.

`trys` gets incremented when there is an incorrect guess. And the remaining bit determines a win or loss.

```
public static void Main()
{
    char[] word = "Stackoverflow".ToLower().ToCharArray();
    char[] blanked = "_____________".ToCharArray();

    int wrongGuesses = 6;
    int trys = 0;

    while (blanked.Contains('_') & trys <= wrongGuesses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter guess: ");
        bool _ = char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out char letterGuess);

        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (word[i] == letterGuess)
            {
                blanked[i] = word[i];
            }
        }

        if (!blanked.Contains(letterGuess))
        {
            trys++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(blanked);
    }

    if (!blanked.Contains('_'))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You won");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You lose");
    }
            
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```